# is "black sign" a common idiom?

Tags: idioms

"black sign" sounds like an idiom which people uses it to refer something bad likely going to be happen. Is it a common idiom and does it have a place in a daily talk?

Comment: While English isn't my native language I have extensive experience with the language and I have never heard this expression or the word "black" being used in this way. I know it's common in other languages though, in my native Swedish the word for moonlighting (i.e. taking illegal employment, not paying taxes) is "black work".

Comment: No, it's not in common use, and I've never heard it.  Idioms using black in this way (to mean sinister or evil) are archaic.  Black now is more likely to be taken literally (the colour) or as a reference to people with dark skin.  It will cause confusion for this reason, don't use it.

Answer (score 1):

The use of 'black' to mean something negative, like 'it's a black day' or 'he had a black heart' is very deprecated in American English. The most common such phrase is likely 'a black mark on your record'. Use of 'black' to mean something bad is likely to cause a lot of acrimony aimed in your direction. This sort of phrasing was much more common centuries ago, but it's best avoided today.

Answer (score -1):

i am a native speaker of the english language and this is tthe first time I am hearing this phrase.

Hence, in my oppinion, it i not a commonly used idiom and generally it is not used in daily talk